# Calculating the median of compound events

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, median

Say I have two independent random variables that occur with two different arbitrary but fixed continuous distributions $D_1$ and $D_2$. I then flip a coin, that occurs heads with probability $p$, to determines if I sample from $D_1$ or $D_2$. How do I calculate the median of this distribution?

If I wanted to calculate the mean, I could use conditional expectation to say: Let $\mu_1$ be the mean of $D_1$, likewise for $\mu_2$ and $D_2$. the expectation for the compound event would then be $p\mu_1 \times (1-p)\mu_2$.

If I compute the median of $D_1$ and $D_2$, can I compute the median of the compound event in a similar manner? I.e. $pm_1 \times (1-p)m_2$?. Does this then generalize to combinations of these compound events?

Comment: When you say "two random events", you mean "two random variables", right? Also, you probably assume that the two variables are independent. If so, explicitly write it in your question.

Comment: @Thanassis Yes, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What is the domain of outcomes for each of your random variables? In other words what values can your variables take? Do they have the same domains? Are the variables discrete or continuous?

Comment: @Thanassis They are continuous (updated in the question as well). Currently the distributions produce the same range of values (positive reals). But I'm also interested in the case where they don't have the same domains. I'm still getting a handle on how to approach this problem but eventually I'd like to add some 'penalty' values if certain outcomes are taken. That is, if each $D_i$ represents a distribution of rewards, there may be some immediate penalty earned before they reward is paid out. But that's for later down the line.